# Troubles sending HTTP request in <b>express.js</b> app deployed on <b>AWS lambda</b> by Serverless Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, aws-lambda, serverless

I always receive an error **Endpoint request timed out** when I implement various functions to communicate through an *HTTP-request* in **APIGateway**.

I would like to receive a **JSON Object** from a function, say B, response when I request */test-communication-A*.

This is the article I followed to explore how the app deploys on Lambda.

[How to deploy a Node.js application to AWS Lambda using Serverless](https://dev.to/adnanrahic/how-to-deploy-a-nodejs-application-to-aws-lambda-using-serverless-2nc7)

```js
method in function-A

app.get("/test-communication-A", function (req, res) {
  request
    .get('https://{endpoint of function-B offered from AWS apiGateway}/test-communication-B')
    .on('response', resp => {
      return res.send(resp);
    })
    .on('error', err => {
      return res.send('error')
    })
});
module.exports.server = sls(app);
```

```js
method in function-B

app.get("/test-communication-B", function (req, res) {
  return res.send({ retCode: 0 });
});
```

Any input would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just to get this straight: you said that /test-communication-B works, right? but when you invoke A and A invokes B, then it times out?

Comment: Yes, all api can be invoke successfully. But when they are invoked in method of functions, it show time-out and even I can't see any logs about the apis of the other function invoked by the beginning one.

Comment: I already remove Access header required. So apis can be public invoked successfully.